# API.ai have the user say something variable

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Hello everyone I'm trying to make a demo with API.ai.

Now I wonder if it's possible to have the user say something variable and using that variable in the response or towards a webhook?

e.g. creating a cluster with name @clustername.
I should be able to say whatever clustername possible and it should return it in the response.

Comment: yes @Tourna this is possible can you explain more about use case

Comment: Well in general i'm going to use it to create a Kubernetes cluster. So in general it would be the user saying "Create cluster". The bot would ask the name of the cluster and it should be whatever the user says. So it's not predefined somewhere.

Comment: `contexts: [{
         name: 'generic',
         parameters: {
          'clustername':'abc'
         }
        }]`

you can do like this

Comment: When you user saying "Create cluster" you need to set contextOut and  when you get generic context send the name in parameters

Comment: I'm doing with the API.ai console atm. I created an entity called @clustername but everytime I try to use it in "User Says" it will only respond properly if the name is in examples.